# PHP How to remove style attribute from HTML tags only in img tag?

Tags: php, regex

I usually use this code in order to remove style attributes from HTML tags.

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);
```

However, now i want to remove style attributes from HTML tags only in an `IMG` tag.

How can i do that?

Comment: for your case, doesn't changing `<` to `<img` work? Anyway manipulating html with regex is always very error prone and you should use a proper xml parser

Comment: could you please show me for example ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to manipulate HTML in PHP, it is safer to use a DOM parser. As an example, here is some code based on DOMDocument/ DOMXPath to get all `img` tags having `style` attributes and remove only those attributes:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<body>
<span style="new">Don't modify it</span>
<span style="old">Don't modify it</span>
<img style="Remove-me" src="img.jpg">
<img src="img.jpg" title="Don't modify it">
</body>
DATA;

// Initializing the DOM tree with an HTML string above
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$imgs = $xpath->query('//img[@style]'); // Fetch all img tags having style attribute

foreach($imgs as $img) { 
   $img->removeAttribute('style'); // Remove the style attribute
}

echo $dom->saveHTML(); // Show the modified HTML
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hFHxM2).

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around. Capture style as a first group and replace it with nothing.

```
$output = preg_replace('/<\s*img[^<>]+?(style\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+[\'\"])/i', '', $input);
```